# Deriving PathInfo class in web routes?

Tags: haskell, happstack

I am reading the [web-routes tutorial](http://www.happstack.com/docs/crashcourse/WebRoutes.html#web-routes) in Happstack, and I have no idea what this is doing:

```
$(derivePathInfo ''Sitemap)

class PathInfo a where
  toPathSegments :: a -> [String]
  fromPathSegments :: URLParser a
```

The doc simply says:

> we use template-haskell to derive an instance of PathInfo for the Sitemap type.

but where does it "store" it? I thought haskell had no state, and is `PathInfo` our own thing, or is it part of happstack?

If someone could explain this, for dummies? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It generates the code that defines an instance of the PathInfo class for the Sitemap type. This isn't "state" as much as "type-global constants". For example, `toPathSegments (Article (ArticleId 5))` will return something like `["Article", "5"]` which in turn will be used to generate a URL like `"/Article/5"`. The other function, `fromPathSegments`, is the inverse operation, parsing `"/Article/5"` back into `Article (ArticleId 5)`.

You could write this instance manually:

```
instance PathInfo Sitemap where
    toPathSegments Home = ["Home"]
    toPathSegments (Article (ArticleId x)) = ["Article", show x]
    fromPathSegments = ...
```

Template Haskell is only used to reduce the need for this boilerplate code.

You might like to read [the chapter on type classes](http://learnyouahaskell.com/types-and-typeclasses) in the book [Learn You a Haskell for Great Good!](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters) which is aimed at Haskell beginners.

Comment: Note that you can see exactly what code is being generated by using the -ddump-splices flag.